# Understanding constant expression

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I'm trying to understand the constant expression concept (from [c++reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization)):

```
struct S {
    static const int c;
};
const int d = 10 * S::c; // not a constant expression: S::c has no preceding
                         // initializer, this initialization happens after const
const int S::c = 5;      // constant initialization, guaranteed to happen first
```

Why isn't the `S::c` a constant expression untill we define it. It was declared as a static **const** data member though...

Comment: [Consider this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbdbdcfc049d957b), where `S::c` isn't ever a constant expression. `const` in general doesn't always imply constant expression.

Comment: @chris Thank you, but now I'm confused even more than I was... I tried to read the 5.20 in Standard and can't see why the S::c is not a core-constant expression in that cases.

Comment: If you want something to be compile-time constant, use `constexpr`. Though there are some cases where `const` will imply `constexpr` for C++98 compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting relevant part of the C++11 standard (draft N3337), section 5.19, paragraph 2:

> A conditional-expression is a core constant expression unless it involves one of the following as a potentially evaluated subexpression (3.2), but subexpressions of logical AND (5.14), logical OR (5.15), and conditional (5.16) operations that are not evaluated are not considered [ Note: An overloaded operator invokes a function. — end note ]:
>
> - an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to
>
>   - a glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a non-volatile const object with a preceding initialization, initialized with a constant expression

There is no preceding initialization of `S::c` in your definition of `d`.

Edit: why this applies:

- `5.1.1/8`: `S::c` is an lvalue.
- `3.10/1`: a glvalue is an lvalue or xvalue.
- `5/8`: specifies that lvalue-to-rvalue conversion happens whenever an operator that expects a prvalue is used.
- Proving that multiplication expects a prvalue is hurting my head. It is implied in many places, but I haven't found anywhere it is said *explicitly*.

Comment: This answer presents a long quote without giving much of an explanation. The question doesn't mention lvalue-to-rvalue conversions or logical operators.

Comment: @ross No, this answer is perfect for me.

Comment: One moment is why the S::c is a glvalue of intergral type. Couldn't you give a little explanation about that?

Comment: @stella I've done my best I think. Standardese makes my head hurt, even when to a human "it's obvious". Tagged the question as language-lawyer though ...

Answer (score 2):

In this sequence …

```
constexpr int d = 10 * S::c;
const int S::c = 5;
```

… the value of `S::c` is not known yet when the `d` value is compiled. But try to swap these lines:

```
const int S::c = 5;
constexpr int d = 10 * S::c;
```

Answer (score 1):

Constant initialization is performed before other initialization in the C++ compiling process. In the example, the constant initialization of `d` is guaranteed to occur before the constant initialization of `S::c`. A constant expression must consist exclusively of constant values. When `d` is initialized, `S::c` is known to be a constant value, so the expression is not considered constant.